# What exactly is the default pcm ALSA device?

Tags: audio, configuration, alsa, defaults

I'm on Lubuntu 20.04, with no PulseAudio installed. I'm having some trouble editing my ALSA setting, as any change I make interferes with my microphone.

In particular, if I use the following basic configuration file:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
}
```

Then I am unable to run OBS and Discord in parallel, as the first tries to open the microphone in stereo mode, while the latter in mono. The last to try always fails to open the device.

However, with just the lines

```
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.ctl.card 2
```

Everything works correctly. This hints to me that the default device that ALSA provides is more flexible than a simple `type hw` plugged to the correct device. I tried to look into somehow making ALSA print its defaults, but could not find anything about it.

How can I replicate the default ALSA device in my configuration file, so that I can make and test my changes as diffs to what ALSA already does for me?

Comment: You solved it with the pair of lines. What is the problem now?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I need to edit my audio file to setup a loopback of my desktop (to record my desktop audio), but every time I try to make an edit my mic stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default definition of the `default` device can be found in `/usr/share/alsa/pcm/default.conf`. If it does not redirect to a driver-specific default, it is defined like this:

```perl
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type hw
        card 2
    }
}
```

The `plug` plugin implements automatic sample rate/format conversion.

Most drivers *do* have their own `default` definition. In particular, most motherboard devices are handled by `/usr/share/alsa/cards/HDA-Intel.conf`, which defines something like this to allow multiple clients:

```perl
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmix:2"
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dsnoop:2"
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, it seems like that `default.conf` file is very generic, with hints and variable names and `@func` being used liberally. The `dsnoop` plugin was the right choice to fix my mic issues. Thanks for the help and hints!